# SQL delete Cascade not working well

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, cascade

I have 3 SQL Server tables:

1. `Country` table with an `id` (int)
2. `City` table with an `id` (int)
3. `CountryCity` table with `countryId` (int) and `cityId` (int)

In my `Country` table, I added the rule `delete cascade` so when I delete the `CountryId` from the `Country` table, all the `CityId` related to the country will be deleted in my `CountryCity` table.

But the ids in my `City` table are not deleted too?

I even added the rule `delete cascade` in my `CountryCity` table also.

Comment: It would be helpful to post your table definitions

Comment: What kind of definition do you need ? all columns are integer

Comment: Show is the create table statements, incl foreign key definitions.

Comment: What would you want to happen if a city was in the CountryCity table for two different countries and you deleted one of those countries?

Comment: That will not happens ! City is unique in each country. You cannot have Los Angeles in two different countries.

Comment: @user708683 Please check my answer

Answer (score 1):

Both Country and City tables ID columns are mapped into CountryCity table as FKs.

By putting a DELETE CASCADE rule on Country and City will result in deletion of rows from mapping table when a row in Country or City table is deleted.

This will however not affect City table if a row in Country table is deleted or vice versa. This is because `DELETE CASCADE` works to delete all referencing rows in other tables, i.e. the rows in tables which have a FK relationship with the current table as PK. CountryCity is the referencing table for both City and Country tables. City table does not reference the CountryCity table and as such `DELETE CASCADE` on the CountryCity table will not result in deletion of the cities.

Since you need this, a solution is proposed below to do this. Do not use DELETE CASCADE but handle deletion yourself like below.

```
    CREATE PROCEDURE deleteCountry
        @countryID NVARCHAR(500) 
    AS 
        BEGIN 
            CREATE TABLE #temp(CityId INT)

            INSERT INTO #temp(CityId)
            SELECT DISTINCT CC.CityId 
                FROM CountryCity CC 
                WHERE CC.CountryID=@countryID

            DELETE FROM CountryCity WHERE CountryID=@countryID
            DELETE FROM Country WHERE ID=@countryID
            DELETE FROM City WHERE ID IN (SELECT CityID FROM #temp)

            DROP TABLE #temp

        END
```

Another way would result in changing your design from 3 tables to 2 table structure like below:

1 - Country table with an id (PK, int, NOT NULL)

2 - City table with an id (PK, int, NOT NULL), CountryId(FK, int, NULL)

And apply `DELETE CASCADE` on the Country table.